# Block page is not affecting with custom theme

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

i am using custome module in my moduleThe code is as follows.

```
function mymodule_init() {
   global $custom_theme;   
   $custom_theme = 'bluemarine';
   init_theme();
}
```

And this works fine for all other pages except the block page(admin/build/block). The block page takes the default theme only. I want the custome theme assigned from mymodule to the block page. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am working in D7 & have not tested this, but I suspect that since Drupal is rendering admin pages using the default theme seven, it may take its que from the path name.  First try changing the path to see if that works.